# Как при нажатии далее, выводить подсвеченное внутри абзаца

Tags: javascript, html, input, checkbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как при нажатии далее, выводить подсвеченное внутри абзаца

Например:

<р>CMS — система управления контентом, используемая для самостоятельного процесса создания, редактирования и управления контентом (фотографии, страницы, товары, категории, новости и т.д.). <\р> Если Подсвечен CMS

Comment: Покажите ваш код и что у вас не работает, попробуем разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант...

```js
(function(){

/*Выбор пунктов...*/
let choose = document.querySelectorAll('.choose');
for(let i = 0; i < choose.length; i++){
  choose[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  });
}


document.getElementById('show-info').addEventListener('click', function(){
  /* Если ничего не выбрано - возвращаемся... */
  if( !document.getElementsByClassName('active').length ){ 
    alert('Выберите один или несколько пунктов'); 
    return; 
  }
  
  this.style.display = 'none'; /* Убираем кнопку "далее" */

  /* Скрываем все кнопки выбора... */
  for(let i = 0; i < choose.length; i++){
    choose[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  /* Показываем только те параграфы, которые идут непосредственно после выбранных .active 
  (селекторы через '+' )  */
  let actives = document.querySelectorAll('.active + .info');
  for(let i = 0; i < actives.length; i++){
    actives[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
});

})();
```

```css
.info {display: none;}
.active {color: white; background-color: #045acf;}
```

```html
<button class="choose">CMS</button>
<p class="info">CMS - это бубу, бубу и бубубу.</p>

<button class="choose">Чат Онлайн</button>
<p class="info">Описание чата...</p>

<button class="choose">Платежная Система</button>
<p class="info">Описание платежных систем</p>

<br><br>

<button id="show-info">Далее</button>
```

Comment: CMS - это вам не бубу! =)